# What is the small peak I see when plotting a noncentral chi squared function?

Tags: probability-distributions, python, chi-squared

When I try to plot a noncentral chi-squared distribution (in Python):

```
from scipy.stats import ncx2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
x =  np.arange(0.0,100.0,0.01)
y = ncx2.pdf(x, df=1.0, nc=10.0)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following:
[image]

I'm wondering what this small peak is near x=0. It seems to be an artifact of my code, but can anyone please explain further?

Comment: It apparently seems unique to the case with 1 d.f. I suspect looking closely at the pdf formula would reveal why, but the noncentral $\chi^2$ formula looks tricky and I don't have experience with it.

Comment: Thank you. So it's supposed to look like that? I assumed it was an issue with the way the code was showing it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken
$$y=\frac{e^{-\frac{x+10}{2} } \cosh \left(\sqrt{10x}
  \right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi x }}$$ Computing the derivative, the minimum corresponds to the zero of function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{10x} \, \sinh \left(\sqrt{10x}\right)-(x+1) \cosh \left(\sqrt{10x} \right)$$ which does not show explicit solution.

Since $x$ is small, using series
$$f(x)=-1+4 x+\frac{15}{2}x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$
which gives an estimate of
$$x \sim\frac{\sqrt{46}-4}{15}=0.1855$$ while the exact solution is $x=0.1829$.

At this point, $y=0.0118$.

Comment: Thank you. So if this is indeed the shape of my function, why do I not see this small peak on any of the images when I search for "noncentral chi-squared distributions"?

Comment: @user1551817. It seems to be only for $1$ d.f. (as  jdods already commented). I also tried to find this case on the Internet but nothing came out. But at least this makes a nice equation to solve. Cheers :-)